# Why are my Divs flashing on screen before hiding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a tabber, and the 3/4 tabs that should be hidden flash on screen before they actually `display:none;`. I've tried adding an extra `.addClass` into my jQuery, tried inline styling `display:none;` on the the divs and have the `display:none` set in my CSS file and still can't solve this? What could be causing this?

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.professor__tabs').each(function() {

    $('.tabs__body', this).addClass('tabs__body--is-hidden');
    $('.tabs__head', this).on('click', function(index) {

        var test = $(this).index();

        $('.tabs__body').addClass('tabs__body--is-hidden');
        $('.tabs__head')
          .removeClass('tabs__head--is-active')
          .filter($(this))
          .addClass('tabs__head--is-active')
          .next('.tabs__body')
          .removeClass('tabs__body--is-hidden');

      })
      .filter(':first')
      .click();
  });
});
```

```css
 .tabs__body {
   -webkit-box-flex: 0;
   -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
   -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
   flex: 0 0 100%;
   -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
   -webkit-order: 2;
   -ms-flex-order: 2;
   order: 2;
   background-color: white;
   padding: 20px;
   min-height: 260px;
   max-height: 410px;
   overflow: auto;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
   display: block;
 }
 .tabs__body--is-hidden {
   display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="professor__tabs">
  <div class="tabs__head">Intro</div>
  <div class="tabs__body">
    1
  </div>

  <div class="tabs__head">Events</div>
  <div class="tabs__body">
    2
  </div>

  <div class="tabs__head">Stream</div>
  <div class="tabs__body">
    3
  </div>

  <div class="tabs__head last-head">Posts</div>
  <div class="tabs__body">
    4
  </div>
```

I noticed that I can't replicate this on JSFiddle, but I'll include my link anyways: **[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/jjehquyh/1/)**

Comment: If you can't replicate it in JSFiddle, surely that would mean it's something else on the page interfering?

Comment: That's what I thought, but I took all the content out and still nothing. I'll add all my content in for the sake of trying, one moment.

Comment: I've just converted your code to a stacksnippet above and it also doesn't show the issue. There must be something else in your document that you aren't including in your question

Comment: If you inline the style right into the element itself, it shouldn't happen. If you add the class which makes the div hidden in jquery, then you may have the flash because the jquery isn't going to execute until your HTML elements have already been loaded and will probably already have been drawn to the screen.

Comment: Hey everyone, try this link (will update in question as well). This has it happen but you have to watch, it's pretty quick. **[check this](https://jsfiddle.net/jjehquyh/1/)**

Comment: @dyagmin I've tried inline-styling `display:none;` it wasn't working how I'd expect it to.

Comment: tabs__body hide this class till DOM loads the page.

Comment: Using display: none; seems to work for me. I'd recommend hiding everything by default and then only showing what's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you hide elements with a script, there will be a period of time when the element is visible. I recommend placing the script to hide it immediately after the element in the web page, or to make use of a loading screen that hides content and only goes away when the page is fully loaded.

This method is useful if you want to cater to browsers that support css but don't support js. Such browsers would never see content hidden by default with css.

```
<div id='myDiv'></div>
<script>
    $('#myDiv').addClass('style--hidden');
</script>
```

Otherwise set the default class to the hidden class and then using jQuery use

```
$(element).removeClass('class-name--hidden');
```

Comment: The script is at the top of the HTML document

Comment: @ether scripts should generally go at the bottom of the document except in special circumstances to avoid render-blocking. In this case if you wanted to use the inline javascript, you'd have to include the jquery library in the head anyway. But you are better off using the second method of hiding the element via css by default unless you are sure your target clients will not have javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way you implemented the hiding feature the browser will not hide the divs until the document is ready - instead by default you should have `.tabs__body--is-hidden` on the divs already using html and then process the visible div via JS.

Comment: I'm working on a solution with the `tabs__body--is-hidden` set on the last 3 divs by default, but having trouble writing JS so that on click, it removes said class.

Comment: @ether wrap the tab header/body in a div and then you can use something like for the on click event `$(this).parent().find('.tabs__body').removeClass('tabs__body--is-hidden')`

Comment: when you reference `($this).parent()` are you referencing the div that I will wrap them in? Would I be able to reference the parent by name? `$('.tab-container').find('.tabs__body').removeClass('tabs__body--is-hidden');` ?

Comment: @ether yes it references the wrapper, the point of using parent is to target the specific wrapper of the link you click, your last sample would select all tab wrappers

Comment: Wrapping divs really messed up design, working on a fix. Since wrapping, essentially makes it a 4-column layout.

Comment: @ether or give them attribute keys so they know which header belongs to which body might be easier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114247/discussion-between-ether-and-david-nguyen).